# Specifying statistical models / Equations between Random Variables

Tags: probability-or-statistics, random

I'm new to Mathematica and confused about how random variables work.

Say I have a standard normal random variable $X\sim \mathcal N(0,1)$ and set $Y := 2X$. Then $\operatorname{Cov}(X,Y) = 2$. Now if I generate $N$-iid. draws for $X$, the sample covariance of $X_1,\dots, X_N$ and $Y_1,\dots, Y_N$ with $Y_n := 2X_n$ should be close to $2$.

My question is: how can I compute statistics (e.g. sample covariance) in Mathematica? Naively, I tried

```
x:=RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], 5000]
y:=2*x
Covariance[x,y]
```

but the result is clearly incorrect (usually not close to $2$), because in actuality (I presume) under this model $Y$ is *independent* of $X$.

What is the most convenient way of achieving the correct result?

Comment: Try `=` instead of `:=` in your code.

Comment: @user64494 oh... Well, thanks. That works! Although, is there an easy way, aside from using loops, to compute Covariance[x,y] for multiple realizations of $X_1,\dots, X_N$? I would like to look at the distribution of, say, Covariance[x,y] next.

Comment: "[...] because in actuality (I presume) under this model  is independent of ." -- Yes, you are correct: using [`SetDelayed`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetDelayed.html) instead of `Set` makes the vectors `x` and `y` given to `Covariance` "independent." Meaning, `y` is computed over a different vector than `x`. Voting to close as a "simple mistake or can be found in the documentation."

Comment: @StefanPerko: Sorry, don't understand your "Although, is there an easy way, aside from using loops, to compute `Covariance[x,y]` for multiple realizations of $X_1 \dots , X_N$?" so can't answer it. Please formulate your question in other words, giving an example.

Comment: @user64494 Well, depending on the draw of $X$, Covariance[x,y] will be some value close to $2$. Repeating the 5000 draws give us different values for Covariance[x,y] each draw, i.e. every time I rerun the notebook I get a different result. How can I e.g. easily compute the mean, variance, a histogram, of Covariance[x,y] over multiple draws of $x$ / over the different results (without rerunning the notebook)?

Comment: @StefanPerko: How about `a = Table[x = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], 10000];
   y = 2*x;
   Covariance[x, y], {j, 1, 10^4}];Histogram[a]` etc? The result sugests a normal distribution.

Comment: @user64494 Thanks! This has been very helpful to me.

Answer (score 2):

While I think this question should be closed (because the main issue of efficiently generating samples without a loop is found in the documentation of `RandomVariate`), the following might help:

```
nSim = 10000;
n = 5;
SeedRandom[12345];
x = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], {nSim, n}];
cov = Covariance[#, 2 #] & /@ x;
Mean[cov]
(* 2.0006 *)
Histogram[cov, "FreedmanDiaconis", "PDF"]
```

And I'm sure you know that the exact distribution is known for your example.

[image: Histogram of covariance of x and 2x]

Comment: Thank you, this also a useful code example. Perhaps I can reword the question somehow to make it worthwhile. Of course I am aware that the distribution here is well-known. My actual goal is looking at significantly more complex statistics involving fractions and exponentials of (joint) moments up to order 4 and with non-zero regression error. This was just supposed to be a simple example.

Comment: Take a look at `TransformedDistribution`, `TruncatedDistribution`, `CensoredDistribution`, `ProbabilityDistribution`, `CopulaDistribution`, `Moment`, `Expectation`, `OrderDistribution`, and `Probability` if you haven't done so already.

Comment: Or if this is closed, certainly ask a new question. Note that having a closed question isn't a personal attack.  The idea is about if the question and answer would be useful to others.  And there's an assumption of minimal knowledge of *Mathematica* (and the Wolfram Language).